# How to use the x:SynchronousMode attribute

Tags: wpf

I want to load a loose xaml file at runtime asynchronously. I read in the msdn documentation that the xaml reader therefore requires the attribute 'x:SynchronousMode="Async"' on the root element of the xaml file. If I define this attribute on the root element, Visual Studio 2012 tells me, that this attribute is not contained in the XAML namespace. Because of this, the designer window, which displays the visual representation of my xaml file, doesn't show anything except "Invalid Markup".

Here are the first lines of my loose xaml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<DockPanel xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       x:SynchronousMode="Async" LastChildFill="True">
```

What is the problem?

Greetings,
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [XamlReader.LoadAysnc()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa346593.aspx) method to load your loose XAML asynchronously?

Comment: Yes, this is what i want to use. But if i define the x:SynchronousMode attribute on my root element, Visual Studio sais that this attribute is not contained in the XAML namespace.

Comment: Can you try deleting the xml tag at top of DockPanel and see if it works?

Comment: `x:SynchronousMode` attribute is used when you try to load the xaml at runtime. You are not able to see the view at design time but was you able to see the loaded xaml at runtime?